# Conversion from 32 bit integer to 4 chars

Tags: c#, encoding

What is the best way to divide a 32 bit integer into four (unsigned) chars in C#.

Comment: What would you expect the chars to be?  ASCII interpretation of the bytes?

Comment: Do you mean chars, or bytes? Chars are individual characters of text in a given encoding, which may correspond to multiple bytes - probably not what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick'n'dirty:

```csharp
int value = 0x48454C4F;
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
  BitConverter.GetBytes(value).Reverse().ToArray()
));
```

Converting the int to bytes, reversing the byte-array for the correct order and then getting the ASCII character representation from it.

EDIT: The `Reverse` method is an extension method from .NET 3.5, just for info. Reversing the byte order may also not be needed in your scenario.

Comment: Is the ultimate goal just to print them to the console?  If not, this method has a lot of unnecessary overhead, compared to Jason and Sam's suggestions.

Comment: @Kip: This is a more portable way to get the bytes for more than just integers, though. The request is rather odd in the first place, though - why would you want to try and encode an integer as characters - unless he really meant to say bytes?

Comment: @Kip: As mentioned in the first place this was a quick and dirty answer. Console.WriteLine was just for me to get some output and proof it's working. The interesting part is the methods used to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 5):

Char? Maybe you are looking for this handy little helper function?

```
Byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
Char c = (Char)b[0];
[...]
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear if this is really what you want, but:

```
int x = yourNumber();
char a = (char)(x & 0xff);
char b = (char)((x >> 8) & 0xff);
char c = (char)((x >> 16) & 0xff);
char d = (char)((x >> 24) & 0xff);
```

This assumes you want the bytes interpreted as the lowest range of Unicode characters.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried it a few ways and clocked the time taken to convert 1000000 ints.

Built-in convert method, 325000 ticks:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(BitConverter.GetBytes(x));
```

Pointer conversion, 100000 ticks:

```
static unsafe char[] ToChars(int x)
{
    byte* p = (byte*)&x)
    char[] chars = new char[4];
    chars[0] = (char)*p++;
    chars[1] = (char)*p++;
    chars[2] = (char)*p++;
    chars[3] = (char)*p;

    return chars;
}
```

Bitshifting, 77000 ticks:

```
public static char[] ToCharsBitShift(int x)
{
     char[] chars = new char[4];
     chars[0] = (char)(x & 0xFF);
     chars[1] = (char)(x >> 8 & 0xFF);
     chars[2] = (char)(x >> 16 & 0xFF);
     chars[3] = (char)(x >> 24 & 0xFF);
     return chars;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do get the 8-byte-blocks:

```
int a = i & 255; // bin 11111111
int b = i & 65280; // bin 1111111100000000
```

Do break the first three bytes down into a single byte, just divide them by the proper number and perform another logical and to get your final byte.

Edit: Jason's solution with the bitshifts is much nicer of course.

Answer (score 0):

.net uses Unicode, a char is 2 bytes not 1

To convert between binary data containing non-unicode text use the System.Text.Encoding class.

If you do want 4 bytes and not chars then replace the char with byte in Jason's answer

Comment: Just for clarification: .net uses Unicode encoded as UCS-2 (ergo the 2 bytes).